# How to use pandas groupby, pivot_table, or crosstab to summarize this dataset

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table, summary

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

[image]

```
account_num = [
    1726905620833, 1727875510892, 1727925550921, 1727925575731, 1727345507414, 
    1713565531401, 1725735509119, 1727925546516, 1727925523656, 1727875509665, 
    1727875504742, 1727345504314, 1725475539855, 1791725523833, 1727925583805, 
    1727925544791, 1727925518810, 1727925606986, 1727925618602, 1727605517337, 
    1727605517354, 1727925583101, 1727925583201, 1727925583335, 1727025517810, 
    1727935718602]
total_due = [
    1662.87, 3233.73, 3992.05, 10469.28, 799.01, 2292.98, 297.07, 5699.06, 1309.82, 
    1109.67, 4830.57, 3170.12, 45329.73, 46.71, 11981.58, 3246.31, 3214.25, 2056.82, 
    1611.73, 5386.16, 2622.02, 5011.02, 6222.10, 16340.90, 1239.23, 1198.98]
net_returned = [
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2762.64, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12008.27, 
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2762.69, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9254.66, 0.0, 0.0]
total_fees = [
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 607.78, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2161.49, 0.0, 
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 536.51, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1712.11, 0.0, 0.0]
flipped = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
proba = [
    0.960085, 0.022535, 0.013746, 0.025833, 0.076159, 0.788912, 0.052489, 0.035279, 
    0.019701, 0.552127, 0.063949, 0.061279, 0.024398, 0.902681, 0.009441, 0.015342, 
    0.006832, 0.032988, 0.031879, 0.026412, 0.025159, 0.023195, 0.022104, 0.021285, 
    0.026480, 0.025837]

d = { 
    "account_num" : account_num,
    "total_due" : total_due,
    "net_returned" : net_returned,
    "total_fees" : total_fees,
    "flipped" : flipped,
    "proba" : proba
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Based on the probability score (proba), I assign each record a decile ([1 - 9]).  From there, I build a table that summarizes various financial statistics.  Each decile is assigned a dollar threshold, such that if the record's total_due amount is greater than the decile's dollar threshold, it is reviewed.  Reviewed records are then eligible to be flipped, and if they are flipped, we can possibly get money returned (net_returned), and received fees (total_fees).

I tried adding the decile assignment and dollar threshold to the DataFrame, but I couldn't figure out how to build the summary table using pandas' groupby, pivot_table, or crosstab.  So, instead, I built the following summary table with the code below:

[image]

```
decile_dict = {
    "Decile 1": [0.074397, 750], "Decile 2": [0.027125, 750], 
    "Decile 3": [0.026380, 750], "Decile 4": [0.025737, 1000], 
    "Decile 5": [0.025058, 2500], "Decile 6": [0.024250, 4000],
    "Decile 7": [0.023185, 5000], "Decile 8": [0.022004, 5000], 
    "Decile 9": [0.021185, 10000], "Rejected": [0.000000, 0]
}

index = []
proba_threshold = []
count = []
percent_all = []
dollar_threshold = []
total_reviews = []
accounts_flipped = []
total_due_reviewed = []
flip_rate = []
total_due_per_flip = []
total_due_per_review = []
dollars_recovered_flipped = []
total_recovered_per_flip = []
total_recovered_per_review = []
total_fees_recv = []
total_fees_recv_per_flip = []
total_fees_recv_per_review = []

df_predictions = df

for key, value in decile_dict.items():
    df_decile = df_predictions[df_predictions.proba > value[0]]
    df_predictions = df_predictions[df_predictions.proba <= value[0]]

    index.append(key)
    proba_threshold.append(str('{:,.5f}'.format(value[0])))
    count.append(f"{df_decile.shape[0]:,}")
    percent_all.append(f"{round(df_decile.shape[0] / df.shape[0] * 100.0, 1)}%")
    dollar_threshold.append(f"${value[1]}")

    df_reviewed = df_decile[df_decile.total_due > value[1]]
    total_reviews.append(f"{df_reviewed.shape[0]:,}")
    accounts_flipped.append(f"{df_reviewed.flipped.sum():,}")
    flip_rate.append(f"{df_reviewed.flipped.mean() * 100.0:,.1f}%")

    total_due_reviewed.append(f"${df_reviewed.total_due.sum():,.2f}")
    total_due_per_flip.append(
        f"${df_reviewed.total_due.sum() / df_reviewed.flipped.sum():,.2f}")
    total_due_per_review.append(f"${df_reviewed.total_due.mean():,.2f}")

    dollars_recovered_flipped.append(f"${df_reviewed.net_returned.sum():,.2f}")
    total_recovered_per_flip.append(
        f"${df_reviewed.net_returned.sum() / df_reviewed.flipped.sum():,.2f}")
    total_recovered_per_review.append(f"${df_reviewed.net_returned.mean():,.2f}")

    total_fees_recv.append(f"${df_reviewed.total_fees.sum():,.2f}")
    total_fees_recv_per_flip.append(
        f"${df_reviewed.total_fees.sum() / df_reviewed.flipped.sum():,.2f}")
    total_fees_recv_per_review.append(f"${df_reviewed.total_fees.mean():,.2f}")

data = {
    "Proba": proba_threshold,
    "Count": count,
    "% All": percent_all,
    "Threshold": dollar_threshold,
    "Reviewed": total_reviews,
    "Flipped": accounts_flipped,
    "FlipRate": flip_rate,
    "TotalDueRevd": total_due_reviewed,
    "DuePerFlip": total_due_per_flip,
    "DuePerReview": total_due_per_review,
    "TotalRecovered": dollars_recovered_flipped,
    "RecvdPerFlip":  total_recovered_per_flip,
    "RecvdPerReview":  total_recovered_per_review,
    "TotalFees": total_fees_recv,
    "FeesPerFlip": total_fees_recv_per_flip,
    "FeesPerReview": total_fees_recv_per_review,    
}
df_results = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index)
```

While I got the desired end result, I have to believe there is a much more elegant and brief solution in Python, especially considering I had to use lists to build my resulting DataFrame.  I'm also afraid this will become a performance and/or memory issue when I attempt to run this solution on a dataset containing millions of records.

So, that's really my question to all you Python experts: is there a better way to solve this problem than the solution I came up with?

For completeness, this is what the table looked like if I performed preprocessing, and added the decile assignment and dollar threshold to it:

[image]

```
def assign_decile(proba):
    decile = "Rejected"
    threshold = 0.0

    if proba > 0.074397:
        decile = "Decile 1"
        threshold = 750
    elif proba > 0.027125:
        decile = "Decile 2"
        threshold = 750
    elif proba > 0.026380:
        decile = "Decile 3"
        threshold = 750
    elif proba > 0.025737:
        decile = "Decile 4"
        threshold = 100
    elif proba > 0.025058:
        decile = "Decile 5"
        threshold = 2500
    elif proba > 0.024250:
        decile = "Decile 6"
        threshold = 4000
    elif proba > 0.023185:
        decile = "Decile 7"
        threshold = 5000
    elif proba > 0.022004:
        decile = "Decile 8"
        threshold = 5000
    elif proba > 0.021185:
        decile = "Decile 9"
        threshold = 10000

    return decile, threshold

df_predictions = df
df_predictions["decile"], df_predictions["threshold"] = zip(
    *df_predictions.proba.apply(assign_decile))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to generate a copy of your source DataFrame (*df*)
with appended *decile* and *threshold* columns, you can do it using
pandasonic *cut* method.

But this method requires bin borders in **ascending** order.
So the first step is to extract bin borders from *decile_dict*,
reverse their order and append *1.0* (the upper limit of the last bin):

```
bord = list(map(lambda lst: lst[0], decile_dict.values()))
bord.reverse()
bord.append(1.0)
```

You should also pass bin **labels**, as they will be used as values of
*decile* column. Their order should also be reversed:

```
lab = list(decile_dict.keys())
lab.reverse()
```

Then, to generate the result, create a copy of the source DataFrame

```
result = df.copy()
```

and append 2 new columns:

```
result['decile'] = pd.cut(df.proba, bins=bord, labels=lab)
result['threshold'] = result.decile.map(lambda kk: decile_dict[kk][1])
```

But if you want also to generate the second DataFrame (statistics per
decile), then a more *pandasonic* approach is to create a function to
compute this statistics:

```
def decStat(grp):
    dec = grp.decile.iloc[0]
    val = decile_dict[dec]
    pt = str('{:,.5f}'.format(val[0]))
    rCnt = grp.shape[0]
    cnt = f"{rCnt:,}"
    pa = f"{round(rCnt / df.shape[0] * 100.0, 1)}%"
    thr = f"${val[1]}"
    rv = grp[grp.total_due > val[1]]
    rvd = f"{rv.shape[0]:,}"
    flp = f"{rv.flipped.sum():,}"
    flpRate = f"{rv.flipped.mean() * 100.0:,.1f}%"
    tdr = f"${rv.total_due.sum():,.2f}"
    dpf = f"${rv.total_due.sum() / rv.flipped.sum():,.2f}"
    dpr = f"${rv.total_due.mean():,.2f}"
    tRec = f"${rv.net_returned.sum():,.2f}"
    rpf = f"${rv.net_returned.sum() / rv.flipped.sum():,.2f}"
    rpr = f"${rv.net_returned.mean():,.2f}"
    fees = f"${rv.total_fees.sum():,.2f}"
    fpf = f"${rv.total_fees.sum() / rv.flipped.sum():,.2f}"
    fpr = f"${rv.total_fees.mean():,.2f}"
    return pd.Series([pt, cnt, pa, thr, rvd, flp, flpRate, tdr, dpf, dpr, tRec,
            rpf, rpr, fees, fpf, fpr],
        index=['Proba', 'Count', '% All', 'Threshold', 'Reviewed', 'Flipped',
            'FlipRate', 'TotalDueRevd', 'DuePerFlip', 'DuePerReview', 'TotalRecovered',
            'RecvdPerFlip', 'RecvdPerReview', 'TotalFees', 'FeesPerFlip', 'FeesPerReview'])
```

Then group the above *result* by *decile* and apply this function:

```
resultByDec = result.groupby('decile').apply(decStat).sort_index()
```

This approach should be substantially faster than yours, especially for
larger amount of source data.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. This is an awesome solution.  Thank you for explaining each step to accomplish the end result.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I accepted your answer. 
 Many, many thanks, again!